# jQuery - Show and Hid div's with different based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Hey all,
I am trying to make a portfolio page for my new website that will display portfolio items in a grid. The functionality of it seems simple but I can't seem to nail down the jQuery. Here is how I need it to work.

1. By default I want all items to be shown.
2. On a specific catagory button click I want it to show the respective divs and hide the rest.
3. These divs have overlapping classes(some items fit into more then one category). Those divs should be shown when either of their respective class buttons are clicked.

Here is what I was trying to use to make it work(it seems bulky, but I'm a jQuery noob):

---

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#showall').click(function(){ 
            $(".item").show("fast");
        })

        $('#webtrigger').click(function(){
             if ($('.web').is(':visible')) {
                 $('.web').show('fast');
                    } else {
                 $('.illustration.print.logo').hide('fast');
             }
         return false;
            })

        $('#logotrigger').click(function(){
             if ($(".logo").is(":visible")) {
                 $(".logo").show("fast");
                    } else {
                 $(".illustration.print.web").hide("fast");
             }
         return false;
            })
     });
```

```
    <a href="#" id="showall">show all</a><br/>
    <a href="#" id="webtrigger">web</a><br/>
    <a href="#" id="illustrationtrigger">illustration</a><br/>
    <a href="#" id="printtrigger">print</a><br/>
    <a href="#" id="logotrigger">logo</a><br />

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="item web">web</div>
        <div class="item illustration">illustration</div>
        <div class="item print">print</div>
        <div class="item logo">logo</div>
        <div class="item web logo">web logo</div>
        <div class="item print illustration ">illustration print</div>
        <div class="item illustration logo">illustration logo</div>
    </div>
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Soo, what's the problem? The code seems alright to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd remove the 'trigger' from the various control `id`s, and add a 'control' `class` to give:

```
<a href="#" id="showall">show all</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="web" class="control">web</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="illustration" class="control">illustration</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="print" class="control">print</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="logo" class="control">logo</a><br />
```

Then use the jQuery:

```
$('a.control').click(
function(){
   var show = this.id;
    $('#wrapper > div.' + show).show();
    $('#wrapper > div:not(".'+show+'")').hide();
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P7EKH/).

Comment: THATS THE TICKET!
simple and sweet.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
$('#webtrigger').click(function(){
     var shown = $('.web').show('fast').get();
     $('#wrapper > item').not(shown).hide('fast');
     return false;
});
```

It stores the ones you're showing in a variable, then uses [`not()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude them from the ones being hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
This is a simple and effective solution, is there any way it can be scalable to work for all the elements without having to write all the code out?

Answer (score 0):

I would make something like this :

```
$('#webtrigger').click(function(){
         $(".item").hide();
         $('.web').show('fast');
        });
```

You hide all items instantaneously, and then show with animation the divs you are interested in.
Of course, it's the same for all triggers you have.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work when you have to pick through the items:

```
funciton tagClicked(e)
{
     var ClassName=$(this).text();
if(ClassName="show all")
{

}
else
{

$.each($('.item'), function(idx,value)
        { 
        if(value.hasClass(ClassName))
        {value.show();}
        else{ value.hide();}
        };
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

`$(document).ready(function(){`

```
$('#showall').click(function()
{

    $(".item").show("fast");
    return false;

})

$('.trigger').click(function()
{

    var triggerType = $(this).attr("id");

    $(".item").hide("fast");

    $('.'+triggerType).show('fast');

    return false;

});
```

});

HTML:

`<a href="#" id="showall">show all

<a href="#" id="web" class="trigger">web

<a href="#" id="illustration" class="trigger">illustration

<a href="#" id="print" class="trigger">print

<a href="#" id="logo" class="trigger">logo`

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item web">web</div>
    <div class="item illustration">illustration</div>
    <div class="item print">print</div>
    <div class="item logo">logo</div>
    <div class="item web logo">web logo</div>
    <div class="item print illustration ">illustration print</div>
    <div class="item illustration logo">illustration logo</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I would do a trick and use the id of the link to trigger the class of the content:

```
 <a href="#" class="showall">show all</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="trigger" id="web">web</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="trigger" id="illustration">illustration</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="trigger" id="print">print</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="trigger" id="logo">logo</a><br />

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="item web">web</div>
        <div class="item illustration">illustration</div>
        <div class="item print">print</div>
        <div class="item logo">logo</div>
        <div class="item web logo">web logo</div>
        <div class="item print illustration ">illustration print</div>
        <div class="item illustration logo">illustration logo</div>
    </div>
```

To show them all by default, use css

```
.item { display:block; }
```

Then jquery to display them:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".showall").click(function(){$(".item").fadeIn(300);});
   $(".trigger").click(function(){
     var contentToDisplay = $("."+this.id);
     if (contentToDisplay.is(":visible")) return;
     $(".item").fadeOut(300); // I prefer this to hide effect
     contentToDisplay.fadeIn(500);
   });
 });
```

Comment: First off, Thanks so much for your reply!

I like this solution as it is scalable to all of the different triggers. I just need to tweak it a little, it wont show specific catagories until I hide all of the items. By default I want the page to show all items.. How can I modify this to do that?

P.S. It is also a little buggy, it doesn't trigger everytime I click.
Here is a working example:

Comment: right, this would actually be better: $(".item").stop().fadeOut(300, function(){contentToDisplay.fadeIn(500);})